# sar high memory commit %

Tags: memory, sar

I've noticed that there's a high percentage of memory committed on this server during a specific timeframe. Although, memory usage still looks fine overall from sar output. I don't see 'out of memory' messages, or anything out of the ordinary in syslog either.

My questions are:
Why does the committed memory jump up so high on this host? Is it possible to track down?
Could this be detrimental to the overall? The articles and blogs I've read so far seem to downplay overcommitted memory, but there are reports of system slowness from the application owner around this timeframe, so I wonder if this was a symptom to an underlying issue.

```
Linux 3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64 (<hostname>)     08/23/2022      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)

07:56:01 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact   kbdirty
07:58:01 PM  63196652  35632716     36.05       568  13826236  24581232     23.86  25069740   8732812         8
08:00:01 PM  63238932  35590436     36.01       568  13782444  24587016     23.87  25054184   8705064        88
08:02:01 PM  62579452  36249916     36.68       568  13776584 122797004    119.19  25522780   8703016       104
08:04:01 PM  56895512  41933856     42.43       568  13776632 201369740    195.46  31050556   8703028        20
08:06:01 PM  61397608  37431760     37.88       568  13776680 319228136    309.86  26314568   8703020         8
08:08:01 PM  60480500  38348868     38.80       568  13776688 476376028    462.39  26919156   8703024        16
08:10:01 PM  60043416  38785952     39.25       568  13776732 554953404    538.67  27197068   8703048        92
08:12:01 PM  59820988  39008380     39.47       568  13784860 574600576    557.74  27375316   8711132         8
08:14:01 PM  59642996  39186372     39.65       568  13785656 613901740    595.88  27472544   8711868         4
08:16:01 PM  59640636  39188732     39.65       568  13785708 613905320    595.89  27473956   8711876         4
08:18:01 PM  59640020  39189348     39.65       568  13785736 613904280    595.89  27473016   8711876         0
08:20:01 PM  59639460  39189908     39.65       568  13785760 613907820    595.89  27473752   8711876         0
08:22:01 PM  59638444  39190924     39.66       568  13785820 613907324    595.89  27474660   8711884         4
08:24:01 PM  59638892  39190476     39.65       568  13785872 613906608    595.89  27474256   8711892         8
08:26:01 PM  59635696  39193672     39.66       568  13785900 613909424    595.89  27475356   8711904         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check ram and swap usage. Adjust swap.

http://www.throwingbones.com/ben/blog/2020-06-15-commit-pct-in-sar/index.html